# Cycle through webpages and copy data

Tags: internet-explorer, vbscript, web-scraping, wsh

I created this script for a friend that cycles through a real estate website and snags email address for her (for promotion).  The site offers them freely, but it's inconvenient to grab one at a time.  The first script dumps each pages data into a txt file called webdump and the second extracts the email addresses from the first txt file.  Save each of these in a separate .vbs file.  If you want to test the script, you may want to change the following to a lower number (this is how many pages are processed):

```
Do while i < 1334
```

The first one errors a ways in and I'm not totally sure why and the second one pulls out a little more than just the email addresses and again, not totally sure why.  I'm not a highly skilled vbs guy, but those issues aren't related to my question...  Question at the bottom...

```
set ie = createobject("internetexplorer.application") 
Set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Dim i
i = 0

Do while i < 1334
i = i + 1

ie.navigate "http://www.reoagents.net/search-3.php?category=1&firmname=&business=&address=&zip=&phone=&fax=&mobile=&im=&manager=&mail=&www=&reserved_1=&reserved_2=&reserved_3=&filterbyday=ANY&loc_one=&loc_two=&loc_three=&loc_four=&location_text=&page="&i
do until ie.readystate = 4 : wscript.sleep 10: loop 

pageText = ie.document.body.innertext 

set fso = createobject("scripting.filesystemobject") 
set ts = fso.opentextfile("c:\webdump.txt",8,true) 
ts.write pageText 
ts.close 

loop

Wscript.Echo "All site data copied!"
```

And the second piece:

```
Const ForReading = 1
Const ForWriting = 8

Set objRegEx = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
objRegEx.Pattern = "@"

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

'Input file
Set objFileIn = objFSO.OpenTextFile("C:\webdump.txt", ForReading)
strOutputFile = "C:\cleanaddress.txt"

Do Until objFileIn.AtEndOfStream
strSearchString = objFileIn.ReadLine
Set colMatches = objRegEx.Execute(strSearchString)  
If colMatches.Count > 0 Then
    For Each strMatch in colMatches 
' Output File
Set objFileOut = objFSO.OpenTextFile(strOutputFile, ForWriting, True)  

IF InStr(strSearchString," ") = 0 THEN
objFileOut.writeline strSearchString
ELSE
objFileOut.writeline Left(strSearchString,InStr(strSearchString," ")-1)


    END IF
    objFileOut.Close
    Set objFileOut = Nothing

    Next
End If
Loop

objFileIn.Close
Wscript.Echo "Done!"
```

I'm able to cycle through the pages on that site easily because of the way the address is...last number of address is sequential, however, now I want to try it with this address:

https://netforum.avectra.com/eweb/DynamicPage.aspx?Site=NEFAR&WebCode=IndResult&FromSearchControl=Yes&FromSearchControl=Yes,

which seems to be java based.  When I click through each page, the address doesn't change.  Is it possible to do something similar to what I've done on the other site in this case?

Comment: It looks like there are no email addresses by the link you provided. Did I miss something?

Comment: There are.  You have to click "Connect with in Social Community" for each, which takes you to a page where it shows.  You may have to be logged in for it to show.  With my previous exercise, each page I clicked had a different address in the address bar.  Not the case with this link.  Is there a way to programmatically click through each page when the address bar doesn't change?  I realize each page takes me to another page where I need to click a link to see the actual email address as you pointed out, but that's a different problem I'll work out.

Comment: To see the email address you click each company name.  You don't have to be logged in, I was mistaken.  Wondering how to dump the data at each page (page 1, 2, 3, etc.) the way I did with the first script when the page address doesn't change.

Comment: There are two ways to scrape the data: to interact with the page via ActiveX `InternetExplorer.Application`, or (if you don't want to use IE due to it's wellknown :) disadvantages) to make few `XMLHTTP` requests - `GET` to receive cookies and other necessary form data, then `POST` for each page, and then `GET` for each link to find out e-mail addresses.

Comment: In my first example, I DO use InternetExplorer.Application, but not sure how to do what you're describing.  For example, if I wanted to directly dump the data on page 5 of this site into a txt file, how should I modify my first script to achieve this?  Just need an example and I'll be on my way...  :)  Not great at writing from scratch, but I can modify like a mofo.  lol  Not saying you have to, but it may help to run the scripts I created here to see what I'm trying to achieve (in case I'm not explaining well).  TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although not complete, not optimal, not bugfree, this could help:

```
' VB Script Document
option explicit

Dim strResult: strResult = Wscript.ScriptName
Dim numResult: numResult = 0
Dim ii, IE, pageText, fso, ts, xLink, Links

  set fso = createobject("scripting.filesystemobject") 
  set ts = fso.opentextfile("d:\bat\files\28384650_webdump.txt",8,true) 

  set IE = createobject("internetexplorer.application") 

  'read first page
  IE.navigate "https://netforum.avectra.com/eweb/DynamicPage.aspx?Site=NEFAR&WebCode=IndResult&FromSearchControl=Yes&FromSearchControl=Yes"
  IE.Visible = True

For ii = 1 to 3 '239
  ts.writeLine "-----------------" & ii
  strResult = strResult & vbNewLine & ii

  While IE.Busy
    Wscript.Sleep 100
  Wend
  While IE.ReadyState <> 4
    Wscript.Sleep 100
  Wend
  While IE.document.readystate <> "complete" 
      wscript.sleep 100
  Wend
  WScript.Sleep 100

  pageText = IE.document.body.innertext
  ts.writeLine pageText

  ' get sublinks and collect them in the 'strResult' variable
  Set Links = IE.document.getElementsByTagName("a")
  For Each xLink In Links
    If InStr(1, xLink.href, "WebCode=PrimaryContactInfo" _
      , vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
      If InStr(1, strResult, xLink.href, vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
      Else
        numResult = numResult + 1
        strResult = strResult & vbNewLine & xLink.href
      End If
    End If
  Next

  ' read a page of the 'ii' index
  IE.Navigate "javascript:window.__doPostBack('JumpToPage','" & ii+1 & "');"
  IE.Visible = True
Next

  ts.writeLine "===========" & numResult & vbTab & strResult
  ts.close 

Wscript.Echo "All site data copied! " _
    & numResult & vbNewline & strResult
Wscript.Quit
```

Explanation:

- navigates to first *page* with usual `http`(s) address
- navigates to next *pages* (of the `ii+1` index) with `javascript` ... `__doPostBack` call (the same as if one fulfill *Jump to Page* field and click the **`GO`** button)
- **not complete**: collects (indirect) links to *Primary Contact Info*
  webpages where e-mail addresses could be found without getting them
- **not optimal**: keeps collecting text of pages visited
- **not bugfree**:

  - works fine with freshly cleared *MSIE* temporary files,
    history and cookies; otherwise starts at an odd (last visited?) *page* of
    [netforum.avectra.com](https://netforum.avectra.com/eweb/DynamicPage.aspx?Site=NEFAR&WebCode=IndResult&FromSearchControl=Yes&FromSearchControl=Yes)
  - navigates to `ii+1`*th page*, so fails on the last one.

Answer (score 2):

Here is true jedi approach :) uses only `XMLHttpRequests`, there aren't IE disadvantages or dependencies from it. Output window created dynamically via `mshta` without temp files. Processing speed can be improved by implementing async requests or multiprocess environment. The only way to stop the script at the moment unfortunately is `wscript.exe` process termination.

```
Option Explicit

Dim oDisplay, sUrl, sRespHeaders, sRespText, arrSetHeaders, sEventTarget, arrFormData, lPage, lMember, i, arrFormStrings, sFormData, arrMembers, arrMemeber, sUrlEmail, sRespTextEmail, sEmail

Set oDisplay = New OutputWindow
sUrl = "https://netforum.avectra.com/eweb/DynamicPage.aspx?Site=NEFAR&WebCode=IndResult&FromSearchControl=Yes"
lPage = 0
lMember = 0

' Initial webpage request
oDisplay.Write("Connecting " & vbCrLf & sUrl)
XmlHttpRequest "GET", sUrl, Array(), "", sRespHeaders, sRespText

' Loop through all pages
Do
    ' Get cookies, form data, listctrl
    oDisplay.Write("Processing page #" & (lPage + 1))
    sEventTarget = ParseFragm("__doPostBack\('(ListControl_[\s\S]*?)',", sRespText)
    ParseResponse "^Set-(Cookie): ([\S]*?=[\S]*?);[\s\S]*?$", sRespHeaders, arrSetHeaders
    ParseResponse "<input type=""hidden"" name=""([\S]*?)""[\s\S]*?value=""([\s\S]*?)"" />", sRespText, arrFormData

    ' Update form params
    For i = 0 To UBound(arrFormData)
        Select Case arrFormData(i)(0)
        Case "__POSTBACKCONTROL"
            arrFormData(i)(1) = "JumpToPage"
        Case "__EVENTTARGET"
            arrFormData(i)(1) = sEventTarget
        Case "__EVENTARGUMENT"
            arrFormData(i)(1) = CStr(lPage)
        End Select
    Next

    ' Jump to page #lPage
    arrFormStrings = Array()
    ReDim arrFormStrings(UBound(arrFormData))
    For i = 0 To UBound(arrFormData)
        arrFormStrings(i) = EncodeUriComponent(arrFormData(i)(0)) & "=" & EncodeUriComponent(arrFormData(i)(1))
    Next
    sFormData = Join(arrFormStrings, "&")
    PushItem arrSetHeaders, Array("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
    PushItem arrSetHeaders, Array("Content-Length", CStr(Len(sFormData)))

    ' New page POST request
    XmlHttpRequest "POST", sUrl, arrSetHeaders, sFormData, sRespHeaders, sRespText

    ' Parse members from new page
    ParseMembers sRespText, arrMembers

    ' Parse members emails, and output 
    For Each arrMemeber in arrMembers
        lMember = lMember + 1
        sUrlEmail = "https://netforum.avectra.com/eweb/DynamicPage.aspx?Site=NEFAR&WebCode=PrimaryContactInfo&ind_cst_key=" & arrMemeber(0)
        XmlHttpRequest "GET", sUrlEmail, Array(), "", "", sRespTextEmail
        sEmail = ParseFragm("""mailto:([a-zA-Z0-9._%+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,6})""", sRespTextEmail)
        oDisplay.WriteTable(Array(CStr(lMember), sEmail, arrMemeber(0), arrMemeber(1)))
    Next

    lPage = lPage + 1
Loop


Sub ParseResponse(sPattern, sResponse, arrData)
    Dim oMatch
    arrData = Array()
    With CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
        .Global = True
        .MultiLine = True
        .Pattern = sPattern
        For Each oMatch In .Execute(sResponse)
            PushItem arrData, Array(oMatch.SubMatches(0), oMatch.SubMatches(1))
        Next
    End With
End Sub

Function ParseFragm(sPattern, sResponse)
    Dim oMatches
    With CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
        .Global = True
        .MultiLine = True
        .Pattern = sPattern
        Set oMatches = .Execute(sResponse)
        If oMatches.Count > 0 Then ParseFragm = oMatches(0).SubMatches(0)
    End With
End Function

Sub ParseMembers(sRespText, arrMembers)
    Dim oMatch
    arrMembers = Array()
    With CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
        .Global = True
        .MultiLine = True
        .Pattern = "<td class[\s\S]*?>([\s\S]*?<[\s\S]*?Key=([\s\S]*?)&[\s\S]*?)</td>"
        For Each oMatch In .Execute(sRespText)
            PushItem arrMembers, Array(oMatch.SubMatches(1), GetInnerText(oMatch.SubMatches(0)))
        Next
    End With
End Sub

Sub PushItem(arrList, varItem)
    ReDim Preserve arrList(UBound(arrList) + 1)
    arrList(UBound(arrList)) = varItem
End Sub

Function EncodeUriComponent(sText)
    With CreateObject("htmlfile")
        .Write ("<script language='JScript'></script>")
        EncodeUriComponent = .DocumentElement.Document.Script.EncodeUriComponent(sText)
    End With
End Function

Function GetInnerText(sText)
    With CreateObject("htmlfile")
        .Write ("<body>" & sText & "</body>")
        GetInnerText = .DocumentElement.Document.GetElementsByTagName("body")(0).InnerText
    End With
End Function

Sub XmlHttpRequest(sMethod, sUrl, arrSetHeaders, sFormData, sRespHeaders, sRespText)
    Dim arrHeader
    With CreateObject("Msxml2.ServerXMLHTTP.3.0")
        .SetOption 2, 13056 ' SXH_SERVER_CERT_IGNORE_ALL_SERVER_ERRORS
        .Open sMethod, sUrl, False
        For Each arrHeader In arrSetHeaders
            .SetRequestHeader arrHeader(0), arrHeader(1)
        Next
        .Send sFormData
        sRespHeaders = .GetAllResponseHeaders
        sRespText = .ResponseText
    End With
End Sub

Class OutputWindow

    Dim oWnd, oDoc, oOutDiv, oCursorDiv, oOutTBody, sSignature, lCols

    Private Sub Class_Initialize()
        sSignature = "OutputWindow"
        ProvideWindow()
    End Sub

    Private Sub ProvideWindow()
        ' source http://forum.script-coding.com/viewtopic.php?pid=75356#p75356
        Dim lWidth, lHeight
        GetWindow()
        If oWnd Is Nothing Then
            CreateWindow()
            With oWnd
                With .Document
                    .GetElementsByTagName("head")(0).AppendChild .CreateElement("style")
                    .stylesheets(0).cssText = "body, td, #output {font-family: consolas, courier new; font-size: 9pt;} #cursor {margin: 3px;} body {background-color: buttonface;} #output {height: 100%; width: 100%; overflow: scroll; background: #FFF;} div.hline {height: 1px; width: 100%; background-color: #000; overflow: hidden;} table {width: 100%; TEXT-ALIGN: center; border-COLLAPSE: collapse; background: transparent; margin-top: 1px;} td {border: black 1px solid;}"
                    .Title = "Output Window"
                    .Body.InnerHtml = "<div id='output'><div id='cursor'><img src='data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAwAJAPAAAAAAAAAAACH5BAkeAAEAIf8LTkVUU0NBUEUyLjADAf//ACwAAAAAAwAJAAACBwxieMnrGgoAIfkECR4AAAAsAAAAAAMACQAAAgSEj6laADs=' /></div></div>"
                End With
                lWidth = CInt(.Screen.AvailWidth * 0.75)
                lHeight = CInt(.Screen.AvailHeight * 0.75)
                .ResizeTo .Screen.AvailWidth, .Screen.AvailHeight
                .ResizeTo lWidth + .Screen.AvailWidth - .Document.Body.OffsetWidth, lHeight + .Screen.AvailHeight - .Document.Body.OffsetHeight
                .MoveTo CInt((.Screen.AvailWidth - lWidth) / 2), CInt((.Screen.AvailHeight - lHeight) / 2)
            End With
        End If
        Set oDoc = oWnd.Document
        Set oOutDiv = oWnd.output
        Set oCursorDiv = oWnd.cursor
        lCols = -1
    End Sub

    Private Sub GetWindow()
        Dim oShellWnd
        On Error Resume Next
        For Each oShellWnd In CreateObject("Shell.Application").Windows
            Set oWnd = oShellWnd.GetProperty(sSignature)
            If Err.Number = 0 Then Exit Sub
            Err.Clear
        Next
        Set oWnd = Nothing
    End Sub

    Private Sub CreateWindow()
        Dim oProc
        Do
            Set oProc = CreateObject("WScript.Shell").exec("mshta ""about:<head><script>moveTo(-32000,-32000);window.document.title=' ';</script><hta:application id=app border=dialog minimizebutton=no maximizebutton=no scroll=no showintaskbar=yes contextmenu=yes selection=yes innerborder=no /><object id='shellwindow' classid='clsid:8856F961-340A-11D0-A96B-00C04FD705A2'><param name=RegisterAsBrowser value=1></object><script>shellwindow.putproperty('" & sSignature & "',window);</script></head>""")
            Do
                If oProc.Status > 0 Then Exit Do
                GetWindow()
                If Not (oWnd Is Nothing) Then Exit Sub
            Loop
        Loop
    End Sub

    Private Sub ChkDoc()
        On Error Resume Next
        If TypeName(oDoc) <> "HTMLDocument" Then ProvideWindow()
    End Sub

    Public Sub Write(sText)
        Dim oDiv
        ChkDoc()
        On Error Resume Next
        Set oDiv = oDoc.CreateElement("div")
        oDiv.InnerHtml = EscapeHtml(sText) & "<div class='hline'></div>"
        oOutDiv.AppendChild oDiv
        oOutDiv.AppendChild oCursorDiv
        oOutDiv.ScrollTop = oOutDiv.ScrollHeight
        lCols = -1
    End Sub

    Public Sub WriteTable(arrCells)
        Dim sInner, oTable, oRow, oTr, oCell, n
        ChkDoc()
        On Error Resume Next
        If UBound(arrCells) <> lCols Then
            Set oTable = oDoc.CreateElement("table")
            oOutDiv.AppendChild oTable
            Set oOutTBody = oDoc.CreateElement("tbody")
            oTable.AppendChild oOutTBody
            lCols = UBound(arrCells)
        End If
        Set oTr = oDoc.CreateElement("tr")
        oOutTBody.AppendChild oTr
        For n = 0 To lCols
            Set oCell = oTr.InsertCell(n)
            oCell.InnerHtml = EscapeHtml(arrCells(n))
        Next
        oOutDiv.AppendChild oCursorDiv
        oOutDiv.ScrollTop = oOutDiv.ScrollHeight
    End Sub

    Public Sub BreakTable()
        lCols = -1
    End Sub

    Private Function EscapeHtml(sCnt)
        Dim n
        sCnt = Replace(sCnt, "&", "&amp;")
        sCnt = Replace(sCnt, """", "&quot;")
        sCnt = Replace(sCnt, "<", "&lt;")
        sCnt = Replace(sCnt, ">", "&gt;")
        sCnt = Replace(sCnt, "'", "&#39;")
        sCnt = Replace(sCnt, vbCrLf, "<br>")
        sCnt = Replace(sCnt, Chr(9), "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;")
        sCnt = Replace(sCnt, "  ", " &nbsp;")
        sCnt = Replace(sCnt, "&nbsp; ", "&nbsp;&nbsp;")
        For n = 0 To 31
            sCnt = Replace(sCnt, Chr(n), "¶")
        Next
        EscapeHtml = sCnt
    End Function

    Private Sub Class_Terminate()
        ' oWnd.close
    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: This is definitely Jedi level.  I've been trying to do the same for realtor.com.  I've been messing with the URL to try to get it to go straight to an agents profile and or show a list of all agents within a state as opposed to having to view agents by a single city only.  For example, I'd like to dump a list of all of the agents emails for Florida.