# Navigate html table using tags to extract inner text (vbs)

Tags: regex, web-scraping, vbscript, xmlhttprequest, wsh

Example of data I'm trying to get (view source):  https://www.myfloridalicense.com/LicenseDetail.asp?SID=&id=8B7B2B88CE03567735560917596FA6BD

The source looks like this:

```
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="2" bgcolor="#e9edf2">
<tr>
    <td width="2%" height="20"><font size="1">&nbsp;</font></td>
    <td width="30%" valign="top"><font face="verdana" size="-1">Name:</font></td>
    <td width="48%">
        <font face="verdana" size="-1"><b>ABBOTT, HUGH ALLAN&nbsp;<small>(Primary Name)</small></b></font></td>

</tr>
```

I can't figure out how to intentionally navigate to this section of the source.  I need to somehow tell it to search all tags with TD for "Name:" and if it exists, give me the very next innertext of the tag

```
<b>
```

which in this case is ABBOTT, HUGH ALLAN.  I need this type of method because looking up specific text with item(#) isn't reliable as the location of the item changes.  I've tried a few different methods, but no success so far.  Such as "for each td in ...." types of methods.  I can eventually arrive at the correct item, but it's unreliable across multiple records.

TIA

EDIT - Here is the code that I have that is close:

This assumes that you have a text file with this path/name (although it says email grab in path, not trying to get emails in this case): "C:\Emailgrab\myfloridalicense.com\Extract URL\AgentURLsRaw_Clean.txt" with these links in it:

https://www.myfloridalicense.com/LicenseDetail.asp?SID=&id=2BEA648A94BA20C0C989E9E0071103AF
https://www.myfloridalicense.com/LicenseDetail.asp?SID=&id=AB8F78E2835A25C2D443B09DE9CDD16F
https://www.myfloridalicense.com/LicenseDetail.asp?SID=&id=A6DBB6CDEE69A637B4497807A1FE45A6
https://www.myfloridalicense.com/LicenseDetail.asp?SID=&id=8B7B2B88CE03567735560917596FA6BD
https://www.myfloridalicense.com/LicenseDetail.asp?SID=&id=27A84B8EF8F96AD4F09AF94774456A39

Also assumes that you have this header file at this path/name: "C:\Emailgrab\myfloridalicense.com\Extract URL\Complete.csv" with these headers:

Last Name, First/Mid Name, Address, License Number, License Status(a), License Status(b), License Expiration, URL

VBS code:

```
Dim URLFile 
Dim fName
set ie = createobject("internetexplorer.application")
IE.Visible = True
Set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell") 
set fso = createobject("scripting.filesystemobject")
Set URLFile = fso.OpenTextFile("C:\Emailgrab\myfloridalicense.com\Extract URL\AgentURLsRaw_Clean.txt")

do while not URLFile.AtEndOfStream 
fName = URLFile.ReadLine()

ie.navigate fName
do until ie.readystate = 4 : wscript.sleep 10: loop 

For Each elm In IE.Document.getElementsByTagName("table")
If elm.getElementsByTagName("TABLE").Length = 16 THEN

name = elm.document.getElementsByTagName("b").item(3).innertext
address = elm.document.getElementsByTagName("b").item(5).innertext
licensenumber = elm.document.getElementsByTagName("b").item(12).innertext
licensestatus = elm.document.getElementsByTagName("b").item(13).innertext
licenseexp = elm.document.getElementsByTagName("b").item(15).innertext

myData =  name & ", " & replace(address, vbCrLf, "") & ", " & licensenumber & ", " & licensestatus & ", " & licenseexp & "," & fName & ", " & vbCrlf

set fso = createobject("scripting.filesystemobject")
set ts = fso.opentextfile("C:\Emailgrab\myfloridalicense.com\Extract URL\Complete.csv",8,true) 
ts.write myData 
ts.close 

end if
next

loop

Wscript.Echo "All Data Copied!"
```

I'm close with my approach, but I don't quite understand why it works for some links and not others.  You can see in the CSV that the data is off in some cases starting at License Number which throws the rest of the columns off.  Also, in some cases in the data there are commas, so I added an extra LicenseStatus column to try to account for this.  I just need a (preferably simple) more reliable way than counting using Item(#).  Hope this helps.  Thank you!

Comment: Possibly duplicate to [VBS Script to cycle through webpages and copy data] (http://stackoverflow.com/q/28384650/3439404), the same OP. As you *know* how-to get the page source, then you could  *know* the most primitive approach: `split` the page  into a zero-based, one-dimensional array containing  substrings by e.g. `</tr>` delimiter. Loop the array, find one containing `Name:` string, split it by `<b>` delimiter...

Comment: Not totally sure I'm following, but I'll research split.  If I can get this piece down, then I think I'll pretty much have what I need to do everything I need.  thx

Comment: I found this: http://www.webmasterworld.com/forum47/1363.htm, but I'm not understanding how to apply it.  Also not seeing anything about jumping OVER that one to find the next innertext, which I have no idea how to ask google that question.  I'm wanting to use "Name:" to know I'm in the right area, so I'll know the very next <b> is the text I need.  I have others to apply this to also, so understanding this will help.  Sounds like you are saying this is possible.  Even a rough example would help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE**

Here is implementation based on HTTP request and RegExp parsing to Dictionary, it takes txt file with URLs as input, and writes result to csv file:

```
arrUrls = Split(ReadTextFile("C:\Emailgrab\myfloridalicense.com\Extract URL\AgentURLsRaw_Clean.txt", 0), vbCrLf)
sCsv = ""
For Each sUrl in arrUrls
    XmlHttpRequest "GET", sUrl, "", "", "", sRespText
    HtmlSimplify sRespText
    ParseToDict "<tr><td></td><td>([^<]*?)</td><td>([^<]*?)(?:</td>){0,1}</tr>", sRespText, oResult
    sCsv = sCsv & """" & oResult("Name:") & """" & ","
    sCsv = sCsv & """" & oResult("Main Address:") & """" & ","
    sCsv = sCsv & """" & oResult("License Number:") & """" & ","
    sCsv = sCsv & """" & oResult("Status:") & """" & ","
    sCsv = sCsv & """" & oResult("Expires:") & """" & ","
    sCsv = sCsv & """" & sUrl & """" & vbCrLf
Next
WriteTextFile sCsv, "C:\Emailgrab\myfloridalicense.com\Extract URL\Complete.csv", 0
WScript.Echo "All Data Copied!"

Function ReadTextFile(sPath, iFormat)
    With CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").OpenTextFile(sPath, 1, False, iFormat)
        ReadTextFile = ""
        If Not .AtEndOfStream Then ReadTextFile = .ReadAll
        .Close
    End With
End Function

Sub WriteTextFile(sCont, sPath, iFormat)
    With CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").OpenTextFile(sPath, 2, True, iFormat)
        .Write(sCont)
        .Close
    End With
End Sub

Sub HtmlSimplify(sCont)
    With CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
        .Global = True
        .MultiLine = True
        .IgnoreCase = True
        .Pattern = "(<[\w\/^<]*)[\s\S]*?>"
        sCont = .Replace(sCont, "$1>")
        .Pattern = "(?:<font>|</font>|<b>|</b>|<small>|</small>|<br>)"
        sCont = .Replace(sCont, "")
        .Pattern = "&nbsp;"
        sCont = .Replace(sCont, " ")
        .Pattern = "[\f\n\r\t\v]"
        sCont = .Replace(sCont, "")
        .Pattern = " +"
        sCont = .Replace(sCont, " ")
        .Pattern = "> <"
        sCont = .Replace(sCont, "><")
    End With
End Sub

Sub XmlHttpRequest(sMethod, sUrl, arrSetHeaders, sFormData, sRespHeaders, sRespText)
    Dim arrHeader
    With CreateObject("Msxml2.ServerXMLHTTP.3.0")
        .SetOption 2, 13056 ' SXH_SERVER_CERT_IGNORE_ALL_SERVER_ERRORS
        .Open sMethod, sUrl, False
        If IsArray(arrSetHeaders) Then
            For Each arrHeader In arrSetHeaders
                .SetRequestHeader arrHeader(0), arrHeader(1)
            Next
        End If
        .Send sFormData
        sRespHeaders = .GetAllResponseHeaders
        sRespText = .ResponseText
    End With
End Sub

Sub ParseToDict(sPattern, sResponse, oDict)
    Dim oMatch, arrSMatches, sSubMatch
    Set oDict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    With CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
        .Global = True
        .MultiLine = True
        .IgnoreCase = True
        .Pattern = sPattern
        For Each oMatch In .Execute(sResponse)
            If Trim(oMatch.SubMatches(0)) <> "" Then oDict(oMatch.SubMatches(0)) = oMatch.SubMatches(1)
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```

Each webpage parsed data is being put to the dictionary with item name as a key. Content of csv is being created by referencing values by it's name but not relative position therefore all columns are in their places for any of listed URLs.
Also I've added double-quoting to avoid splitting into separate columns values with commas like `Current,Inactive` (RFC 4180 point 2.6).
It's not a universal solution for any web site. For another website you have to create appropriate RegExp pattern for parsing. In this case I saved HTML content to the file after `HtmlSimplify`, and examined it to figure out desirable pattern. More of that, to use this approach for more complex sites, you might have to parse in few steps (might be looped) by cutting off extraneous HTML parts thus narrowing the search.

**SOURSE**

Consider this `VBS` parser:

```vb
' sCont contains table HTML at the moment

With CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
    .Global = True
    .MultiLine = True
    .IgnoreCase = True
    ' content simplification
    .Pattern = "(<[\w\/^<]*)[\s\S]*?>"
    sCont = .Replace(sCont, "$1>")
    .Pattern = "(?:<font>|</font>|<b>|</b>|<small>|</small>|<br>)"
    sCont = .Replace(sCont, "")
    .Pattern = "&nbsp;"
    sCont = .Replace(sCont, " ")
    .Pattern = "[\f\n\r\t\v]"
    sCont = .Replace(sCont, "")
    .Pattern = " +"
    sCont = .Replace(sCont, " ")
    .Pattern = "> <"
    sCont = .Replace(sCont, "><")
End With
ParseToArray "<tr><td></td><td>([^<]*?)</td><td>([^<]*?)(?:</td>){0,1}</tr>", sCont, arrResult

' continue processing of arrResult
WScript.Echo arrResult(0)(1) ' eg shows name
' ...

Sub ParseToArray(sPattern, sResponse, arrMatches)
    Dim oMatch, arrSMatches, sSubMatch
    arrMatches = Array()
    With CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
        .Global = True
        .MultiLine = True
        .IgnoreCase = True
        .Pattern = sPattern
        For Each oMatch In .Execute(sResponse)
            arrSMatches = Array()
            For Each sSubMatch in oMatch.SubMatches
                PushItem arrSMatches, sSubMatch
            Next
            PushItem arrMatches, arrSMatches
        Next
    End With
End Sub

Sub PushItem(arrList, varItem)
    ReDim Preserve arrList(UBound(arrList) + 1)
    arrList(UBound(arrList)) = varItem
End Sub
```

Starting with `sCont` as follows:

```xml
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="1" width="100%" border="0" bgcolor="#b6c9dc"><tr><td>
    <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="3"><tr>
        <td width="32%"><font face="verdana" size="-1"><b>Licensee Information</b></font></td>
    </tr></table>
    <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="2" bgcolor="#e9edf2">
    <tr>
        <td width="2%" height="20"><font size="1">&nbsp;</font></td>
        <td width="30%" valign="top"><font face="verdana" size="-1">Name:</font></td>
        <td width="48%">
            <font face="verdana" size="-1"><b>ABBOTT, HUGH ALLAN&nbsp;<small>(Primary Name)</small></b></font></td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td width="2%" height="20"><font size="1">&nbsp;</font></td>
        <td width="30%" valign="top"><font face="verdana" size="-1"></font></td>
        <td width="48%"><font face="verdana" size="-1"><b>&nbsp;<small>(DBA Name)</small></b></font></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td width="2%" height="20"><font size="1">&nbsp;</font></td>
        <td width="30%" valign="top"><font face="verdana" size="-1">Main Address:</font></td>
        <td width="68%"><font face="verdana" size="-1"><b>318 TURKEY CREEK 
        <br>ALACHUA&nbsp;&nbsp;Florida&nbsp;&nbsp;32615</b></font>
        </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td width="2%" height="20"><font size="1">&nbsp;</font></td>
        <td width="30%" valign="top"><font face="verdana" size="-1">County:</font></td>
        <td width="68%"><font face="verdana" size="-1"><b>ALACHUA
    </tr>



    <tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
    <tr>
        <td width="2%" height="20"><font size="1">&nbsp;</font></td>
        <td width="30%" valign="top"><font face="verdana" size="-1">License Mailing:</font></td>
        <td width="68%"><font face="verdana" size="-1"><b>318 TURKEY CREEK

        <br>ALACHUA&nbsp;&nbsp;FL &nbsp;&nbsp;32615</b></font>

    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td width="2%" height="20"><font size="1">&nbsp;</font></td>
        <td width="30%" valign="top"><font face="verdana" size="-1">County:</font></td>
        <td width="68%"><font face="verdana" size="-1"><b>ALACHUA
    </tr>

    <tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
    <tr>
        <td width="2%" height="20"><font size="1">&nbsp;</font></td>
        <td width="30%" valign="top"><font face="verdana" size="-1">LicenseLocation:</font></td>
        <td width="68%"><font face="verdana" size="-1"><b> 

        <br>&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; </b></font>

    </tr>

    </table>

</td></tr></table>
```

It gets array of sub-arrays as shown below on the locals debugger screenshot:

[image: Locals array screenshot]

Comment: This looks complex.  I appreciate the work!  Forgive me, not totally sure how to run it.  The output looks like it tells me where in the table these items fall, which is great...or is that the "locals debugger" you referenced?   Forgive my newbness...  I would like to know how to reference subarrays specifically without pattern matching...just because I want to be able to apply this to other things...or will this always apply in any table situation?

Comment: Thank you for this!  It looks promising.  For the updated solution, I'm getting error "The parameter is incorrect" code: 80070057, source: msxml3.dll.

Comment: Could you specify error line? It will be helpful if you debug the code e. g. with MS Script Editor (run via shortcut where command line should be `wscript.exe //d c:\test\test.vbs` for x86, or `c:\windows\syswow64\wscript.exe //d c:\test\test.vbs` for x64), VbsEdit or other, to find out variables values, especially `sUrl`. Finally you can just add `WScript.Echo(sUrl)`. It looks like `arrUrls = Split(...)` works wrong, and 'sUrl' gives empty string value.

Comment: I ran the x64 command as you said and I get the same msxml3.dll error message.

Comment: Well, I expect that line, and **what is the `sUrl` value?** Has you MS Script Editor installed? Does it's window appear on error? I guess your txt file has an excessive new line symbols. I've tried to pass empty `sUrl` to `.Open` method, and got the same error as you.

Comment: I do not appear to have this installed.  I don't understand, there are no blank URLs.

Comment: I've not been able to implement your method completely, but some of the elements of your response DID lead me to a working solution.

Answer (score 0):

I've not been able to implement your method completely, but some of the elements of your response DID lead me to a working solution.  I used a combination of IF statements to shift each item over the necessary number of columns if the "License Number" column contains something other than a license number.  Also used your suggestion to have the replace function take care of the comma issue.  That was PART of my issue right there that was throwing things off.

```
Dim URLFile 
Dim fName
set ie = createobject("internetexplorer.application")
IE.Visible = True
Set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell") 
set fso = createobject("scripting.filesystemobject")
Set URLFile = fso.OpenTextFile("C:\Emailgrab\myfloridalicense.com\Extract URL\AgentURLsRaw_Clean.txt")

do while not URLFile.AtEndOfStream 
fName = URLFile.ReadLine()

ie.navigate fName
do until ie.readystate = 4 : wscript.sleep 10: loop 

For Each elm In IE.Document.getElementsByTagName("table")
If elm.getElementsByTagName("TABLE").Length = 16 THEN

name = elm.document.getElementsByTagName("b").item(3).innertext
address = replace(elm.document.getElementsByTagName("b").item(5).innertext,","," ")

'License Number
If InStr(elm.document.getElementsByTagName("b").item(12).innertext, "Real Estate Broker or Sales") THEN 
licensenumber = elm.document.getElementsByTagName("b").item(14).innertext 
ELSEIf InStr(elm.document.getElementsByTagName("b").item(12).innertext, "Broker") or InStr(elm.document.getElementsByTagName("b").item(12).innertext, "Sales Associate") THEN
licensenumber = elm.document.getElementsByTagName("b").item(13).innertext
Else licensenumber = elm.document.getElementsByTagName("b").item(12).innertext
End If

'License Status
If InStr(elm.document.getElementsByTagName("b").item(12).innertext, "Real Estate Broker or Sales") THEN 
licensestatus = elm.document.getElementsByTagName("b").item(15).innertext 
ELSEIf InStr(elm.document.getElementsByTagName("b").item(12).innertext, "Broker") or InStr(elm.document.getElementsByTagName("b").item(12).innertext, "Sales Associate") THEN
licensestatus = elm.document.getElementsByTagName("b").item(14).innertext
Else licensestatus = elm.document.getElementsByTagName("b").item(13).innertext
End If

'License Exp
If InStr(elm.document.getElementsByTagName("b").item(12).innertext, "Real Estate Broker or Sales") THEN 
licenseexp = elm.document.getElementsByTagName("b").item(17).innertext 
ELSEIf InStr(elm.document.getElementsByTagName("b").item(12).innertext, "Broker") or InStr(elm.document.getElementsByTagName("b").item(12).innertext, "Sales Associate") THEN
licenseexp = elm.document.getElementsByTagName("b").item(16).innertext
Else licenseexp = elm.document.getElementsByTagName("b").item(15).innertext
End If

myData =  name & ", " & replace(address, vbCrLf, "") & ", " & replace(licensenumber, ","," ") & ", " & replace(licensestatus, ","," ") & ", " & replace(licenseexp,","," ") & "," & fName & ", " & vbCrlf

set fso = createobject("scripting.filesystemobject")
set ts = fso.opentextfile("C:\Emailgrab\myfloridalicense.com\Extract URL\Complete.csv",8,true) 
ts.write myData 
ts.close 

end if
next

loop

Wscript.Echo "All Data Copied!"
```